# content_translation_update_8400 causes syntax error

Tags: updating

I just tried updating a Drupal v8.3.7 site to v8.4.4 and when running `drush updb` I get this error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     [error]
server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET content_translation_source='und'
WHERE content_translation_source IS NULL' at line 1: UPDATE {} SET content_translation_source=:db_update_placeholder_0
WHERE content_translation_source IS NULL; Array
(
[:db_update_placeholder_0] => und
)

Performing content_translation_update_8400                  [ok]
```

It says the **"content_translation_update_8400"** is ok but that is not true. Every update hook after this one does not get invoked. This causes a very big problem when updating Drupal and the Drupal sites I am maintaining need to be update-to-date.

So, what is the problem here?